# How secure is data stored using chrome.storage.local.set

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm storing options data in a chrome extension using chrome.storage.local.set

How secure is that data?

Can it be read easily by anyone who has access to the file it is stored in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not secure, and [per the official chrome.storage docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is stored unencrypted in the user's profile folder under their Chrome data directory. You will need to use some additional encryption if you are storing more sensitive data using these APIs.

They are stored in a [LevelDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB) database in the following location:

```
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings\<Extension id>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It's saved in the following path (For other OS, the path is similar), can be easily accessed.

   ```
   C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings\<Extension id>
   ```
2. Basically, since the data is saved in local machine, you can't trust it as secure, since there're tons of ways to get the data. For example, other extension/scripts may overrite `chrome.storage.local.set` and they may get the data first, like what [Storage Area Explorer](https://github.com/jusio/storage-area-explorer) does.